Prevent Whatsapp from making backups if option "No Backup" is chosen in settings
How can I completely stop Whatsapp's attempts to make a backup?
I chose the option "never" for backup of Whatsapp chats. However, I get the message "Backup could not be completed" at least once a day. It looks like Whatsapp is trying to make backups despite of my choice of "never".
I have done the following:

uninstall & reinstall Whatsapp
delete cache
remove Google account
force stop of the App

Hardware and software data: One UI-Version 6.1 / Android-Version 14 / Whatsapp Version 2.24.21.79

Related/possible dupe: Prevent WhatsApp from automatically backing up messages (kind of old, not sure if the solution is still applicable)

Unfortunately, it's not applicable. If it just was a local backup, it would be acceptable. However, if it ends in a recurring and persistent error message as in my case, there is something wrong.

I think there are actually 2 tangential issues here, 1) prevent offline backup (AFAIK, not possible from WhatsApp settings), and 2) "Backup could not complete" (unknown factors). The "never" option is actually only applicable to cloud backup.
